# Show $U_{n}$ is open but sequence does not converge

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-explanation, problem-solving

This is not homework

I am dealing with infinite product topology

Source:Conover,**A First Course in Topology**

First a definition for reference

**3.1** **Definition**
Let $\Lambda$ be a any nonempty set such that for each $\lambda \in \Lambda$ there
is a nonempty set $X_{\lambda}$ The Cartesian product of {$X_{\lambda}$:
$\lambda \in \Lambda$ } is defined to be:

$\Pi_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ $X_{\lambda}$=
{x:$\Lambda$$\to \bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda} X_{\lambda}$:
x($\lambda$)$\in X_{\lambda}$ for each $\lambda\in\Lambda$}

the set of all functions x from the the index set $\Lambda$ to the union of the
factors($\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$$X_{\lambda}$) such that for each $\lambda\in\Lambda$, x( $\lambda$)$\in$ $X_{\lambda}$

**Exercise 3.7.1 page 100**

Let {$X_n$:n$\in$ $Z^{+}$} be a a countable collection with $X_n$=**R** with
the usual topology. Consider the sequence
{($\frac{1}{n}$,$\frac{1}{n}$,…):n$\in $$Z^{+}$} $\subset $$\Pi X_i$Certainly the sequence should converge to the point $(0,…,0)$ $\in \Pi X_i$ But if we try to over control the
product space by requiring that the product of open sets to be open be
it will not

For each n$\in$ $ Z^{+}$,put $U_n$=(-$\frac{1}{n}$, $\frac{1}{n}$)

(1) Show that each $U_n$ is open in **R** but the sequence
{($\frac{1}{n}$, $\frac{1}{n}$…):n$\in $$Z^{+}$} is never in
$\Pi U_i$, so if the set is open in the product
{($\frac{1}{n}$,$\frac{1}{n}$,…):n$\in $$Z^{+}$ }
will not converge to $(0,…,0)$ which is not reasonable.

I think it is
reasonable that it doesn’t
converge ,since the sequence is not in the
product space.

**My attempt**

Let {$X_n$:n$\in$ $Z^{+}$} be a countable collection with $X_n$=**R** with
the usual topology.

Let $\Lambda$ be our indexing set and |$\Lambda$|$\geq$ $\aleph_{0}$.

For each n$\in$ $ Z^{+}$,Put $U_n$=(-$\frac{1}{n}$, $\frac{1}{n}$)

Let U=$\Pi U_i$ be basic open set containing
$(0,..,0)$ If $U_i\ne\emptyset$ and $U_i =X_i$, $U_i$ is open.
Since {($\frac{1}{n}$,$\frac{1}{n}$,…):n$\in $$Z^{+}$ }$\notin$ $\Pi U_i$ then for each $U_i$ ,$\frac{1}{n} \notin U_i$
Also $\bigcap U_i=${ ${0}$} which is not open l Thus the sequence diverges

As to openess,

R$\setminus$(-$\frac{1}{n}$,$\frac{1}{n} $)= (-$\infty$,-$\frac{1}{n}$)$\cup$($\frac{1}{n}$,$\infty$)

Interior point is the empty set.

Comment: I doubt if I got any of this correct. I proved it converges for a finitely many of them ,which was another question. I found enough info on how to do it. How do you define over control?
If you reword Def 3.1 so you force all sets to be open, that could make the
sequence diverge.l would like to know how
to it properly.

Though this problem seems a contradiction.

Comment: The least you could do is to reproduce the problem is it is stated in that textbook. The sequence that the author mentions is the sequence $\bigl(\frac1n,\frac1n,\ldots\bigr)_{n\in\Bbb N}$, which *belongs* to the space.

Comment: There now it is verbatim @JoseCarlosSantos

Comment: I still see $\left(\frac1n,\ldots,\frac1n\right)$, instead of $\left(\frac1n,\frac1n,\ldots\right)$ in more than one place.

Comment: The problem with how you're stating the question is that you're using the same "dummy" letter, $n$, to mean two different things.  You should use one letter to represent the coordinates of the points in your sequence and a different letter to represent the component of your open set.  You're really trying to say:

$$\left (\frac 1m \mid k \in \Bbb N \right ) \notin \prod_{n \in \Bbb N} U_n.$$

The key is that I'm using different letters $m$ and $n$ to describe the point in your space and the open sets comprising the product.

Comment: This is motivating why we use the product topology instead of the box topology.

Comment: Ok I will do that in future posts. Your notation is clearer and superior to the author’s